# How to modify the CPU throttle temperature?

Tags: cpu, temperature, throttling, cpu-throttling

I have a Xeon E5430 in a socket 775 board. Most of the apps are getting the CPU temperature wrong. Only aida64 is okay, the others think the CPU temperature is about 20°C higher than the reality. I guess Windows or the motherboard or whatever throttles the CPU thinks that too, since when the CPU hits the T case on the wrongly working program, it starts to be throttled and the applications sometimes crash because of this. So for example when I play with battlefield 4, I got a crash in every 2-3 hours, because the CPU reaches the 49°C and the T case is 67°C. This is very annoying. Is there a solution to change the temperature and verify that I am right about this?

Comment: I'd post an answer if I could find something specific to back me up but Throttling is in *hardware* - there's literally an on processor sensor that does these things I thought.

Comment: What makes you think the tcase for the E5430 is that low?

Comment: @Ramhound https://ark.intel.com/products/33081/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5430-12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB

Comment: I found that the Tjmax is 100°C by default on the hwinfo, and it is 85°C on this CPU. If I set it to 85°C it shows correct temp data. I guess the mobo has the 100°C tjmax too, that's why the cpu starts throttling around 49°C.

Comment: `it starts to be throttled and the applications sometimes crash because of this`. Uhm what? No, that should **not** happen. Slow down during throttling: yes. Crash? Nope nope nope nope. That crash is from a different reason.

Comment: @Hennes I have a 3 hours hwinfo log and the crash happened the same time as it started to throttle. I found out that the BIOS does not have proper microcode for this Xeon CPU. I'll mod the BIOS maybe that solves the stability issues.

Comment: Well, in that is is not due to the throttling itself but because it went into a valid and perfectly working state which the motherboard firmware (in your case BIOS) did not expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by installing a modded BIOS. http://tanieprocesory.pl/en/bios2-2/

Now it supports the CPU properly at least I tested it for 2 hours. I update this later if there is any instability. Apparently the Tjmax is fixed as well, at least I don't have throttlnig around 49°C and I can use this CPU with the fan set to 200 RPM (instead of 800 RPM). This is nice, I hope the system will be more stable too on the long run.